# Intellij Rust Default to --release mode for test configurations

Tags: rust-cargo, intellij-rust

### Context

The default "Command" for running a rust test in CLion is:

`test --package ... --lib ... -- --exact`

(This is generated by pressing a green triangle on a specific test method)

### Problem

I'd like to be able to change the default to include the `-r` flag for running in release mode.

This would allow me to forego having to edit each generated configuration every time I run a new test.

### Question

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: I don't see an easy way to change it. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/blob/13be60cb7fae04f64064dc84d165dc4ed4ed070a/src/main/kotlin/org/rust/ide/newProject/Utils.kt#L79), the default string is hardcoded in the configuration factory.

Comment: Very unfortunate.